# Benchmark for Windows Server vs. Server Core

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows, windows-server-core

Are there any known and sound benchmarks comparing a standard Windows Server 2008 with a Server Core installation? I guess a realistic workload like SQL Server or a web application running under IIS would be important.

Comment: I don't think Core vs server was done to provide a performance gain, although it likely would in a large enough environment.  I think the driver is to reduce the vulnerability footprint

Comment: @uSlackr, I think you are right but one might argue that less memory usage and less CPU cache churn might improve performance. Also, less periodic background activity.

Comment: The RAM footprint is certainly smaller, but I don't think it will have much impact on CPU cycles, to be honest.

Comment: @MDMarra that might be true, but it would be interesting to know for sure!

Answer (score 2):

Just benchmark these services like you normally would with command-line tools that work on both like sqlio.